# Apache CXF: Consume XML POST payload with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type set

Tags: rest, cxf

We got a REST service implemtented in Apache CXF available for our client exposed like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/process")
public Response processBean(Bean bean);
```

The *Bean* object is annotated with @XmlRootElement and all this works great. The problem is that the client is not setting the right content-type (should be "application/xml" but client sets "application/x-form-urlencoded").

Apache CXF is not regonizing the method as a valid method for the (incorrect) call since the content-type is wrong. If I change @Consumes to "*/* or application/x-www-form-urlencode" Apache CXF does not know how to parse the POST payload (no MessageBodyReader). 
The client will eventually change the header but we need a quick fix for now.

Any ideas? Do I need to use some XmlMessageBodyReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking at look a using a [filter](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html) to modify the content type to the value that your code is expecting.