# CXF Restful web service with generic payload

Tags: rest, cxf

Is there a way in CXF to implement a Restful webservice which will accept different xml requests using one Web service method?

e.g. Can one create a Restful endpoint to accept this type of XML through one web service method?

```
  <Data>
  <Book>BN1</Book>
  </Data>
```

& this too using same web service method?

```
<Data>
  <Disk>DN1</Disk>
  </Data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I am using this for generic XML.

```
public interface Callback {

    @POST
    @Path("/submit")
    @Consumes("text/xml")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response submit(String incomingXML);


}
```

Basically I am getting whole xml as a string in my method body, As CXF is not parsing it, it can remain generic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post: [Apache CXF: Consume XML POST payload...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010595/apache-cxf-consume-xml-post-payload-with-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-co) shows a good example of how to declare a CXF REST service as receiving POST XML data.

For your example of handling different XML content, instead of 'Bean' in the above you'd have an `@XmlRootElement` that's the Data, with a child that's a `@XmlAnyElement`.

Comment: Thanks kevinjansz. I am also using @XmlAnyElement for now. I was wondering if there is a possibility to use something similar to MessageType as POJO, Payload etc as in CXF SOAP based services. In Soap based services the whole message was handed over as XML DOM document to the webmethod which was really powerful and handy.